# Python OrderedDict ordered by date

Tags: python, datetime, date, ordereddictionary

I am trying to use an OrderedDict (Raymond Hettingers [version](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/) for pre2.7 Python) where my keys are dates. However it does not order them correctly, I imagine it may be ordering based on the ID.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how this could be done?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what ou call a date?

Comment: Can you give us an example how are you trying to achieve that? On my system(Original Python implementation), it works correctly.

Comment: Bear in mind that it is an *ordered* dictionary, not a *sorted* dictionary. (The lack of comprehension of the difference between "ordered" and "sorted" is something that I keep running into in my software engineering course at Uni, even from a couple of lecturers.)

Comment: @Chris you are right, I've misunderstood. I was appraoching this as if it was a sorted dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrderedDict, according to its docstring, is a kind of dict that remembers insertion order.
Thus, you need to manually insert the key/value pairs in the correct order.

```
# assuming unordered_dict is a dict that contains your data 
ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
for key, value in sorted(unordered_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda t: t[0]):
    ordered_dict[key] = value
```

edit: See utdemir's answer for a better example. Using `operator.itemgetter` gives you better performance (60% faster, I use the benchmark code below) and it's a better coding style. And you can apply `OrderedDict` directly to `sorted(...)`.

```
a = (1, 2)

empty__func = 0
def empty():
    for i in xrange(N_RUNS):
        empty__func

lambda_func = lambda t: t[0]
def using_lambda():
    for i in xrange(N_RUNS):
        lambda_func(a)

getter_func = itemgetter(0)
def using_getter():
    for i in xrange(N_RUNS):
        getter_func(a)
```

Comment: @juanchopanza No I just compared plain itemgetter with lambda in a loop. See the code above.

Answer (score 9):

```
In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: import operator

In [3]: from datetime import date

In [4]: d = {date(2012, 1, 1): 123, date(2010,2,5): 542, date(2011,3,3):76 }

In [5]: d # Good old dict
Out[5]: #it seems sorted, but it isn't guaranteed to be that way.
{datetime.date(2010, 2, 5): 542,
 datetime.date(2011, 3, 3): 76,
 datetime.date(2012, 1, 1): 123}

In [6]: o = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0)))

In [7]: o #Now it is ordered(and sorted, because we give it by sorted order.).
Out[7]: OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2010, 2, 5), 542), (datetime.date(2011, 3, 3), 76), (datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), 123)])
```

Comment: Actually, while you use `date`s as the keys, it *is* guaranteed to be sorted (remember to call it *sorted*, not *ordered*), at least in the current implementation in CPython. Dictionary item order is worked out by item comparison, which is properly defined for `datetime.date`. So if you wanted to do it with such a key type, you could use a `dict` rather than an `OrderedDict` (and you would remember to put in a comment about the behaviour you were depending on - another implementation of Python might not break this behaviour.)

Comment: @Chris, I cannot see how the `OrderedDict` could satisfy its promise to maintain the order of insertion AND order by item comparison. And plain old `dict` uses hashing, and no order can be assumed.

Comment: @Chris Morgan, on my system, Python 2.7.2 and Python 3.2.1, dict's arent sorted.

Comment: @utdemir Ah I forgot to use itemgetter.. It's better both in performance and in comprehensibility.

Comment: Hmm.  I seem to have made a slip somewhere in learning; my understanding of `dict`s was not correct. Sorry.

Comment: @Overmind: actually, `, key=operator.itemgetter(0)` is superfluous; `dict.items()` returns a `list` of `(key, value)` `tuple`s. `tuple` comparison is done by comparing first items, then if they're the same second, et cetera. But the first items will all be distinct as they've been used as keys in the `dict`. So it basically implies first item comparison (but is faster).