# How can I prevent OrderedDict inserting an element rather than adding it to the end?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

> [An OrderedDict is ordered by the order items are added to
>   it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17814958/283650)

So why is this happening?

I have two dictionaries:

```
d_names
d_new_names
```

The second is a re-ordered version of the first. This is because I understand that [I cannot re-order an existing OrderedDict - I need to create a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031418/how-to-sort-ordereddict-in-ordereddict-python/8031431#8031431).

To do this I first create an ordered list:

```
l_new_names = []
for s_number in d_names:
    for s_week_number in d_names[s_number]:
        l_new_names.append([s_number, s_week_number])

print "l_new_names before sort = %s" % l_new_names
l_new_names.sort()
print "l_new_names after sort = %s" % l_new_names
```

Then I create and fill the first level of the new dictionary:

```
d_new_names = ordereddict.OrderedDict()

for s_number, _ in l_new_names:
    if s_number in d_new_names:
        print "NOT creating d_new_names[%s]" % s_number
    else:
        print "creating d_new_names[%s]" % s_number
        d_new_names[s_number] = {}
        d_new_names[s_number][NAME] = d_names[s_number][NAME]
```

Then I create the second level and fill the dictionary:

```
for s_number, s_week_number in l_new_names:
    d_new_names[s_number][s_week_number] = {}
    d_new_names[s_number][s_week_number][DATE] = d_names[s_number][s_week_number][DATE]
    d_new_names[s_number][s_week_number][PRICE] = d_names[s_number][s_week_number][PRICE]
```

When I wrote the dictionary contents to a file I was surprised to see this order:

```
writing week:13
writing week:15
writing week:14
writing week:16
```

That is, week 15 precedes week 14.

Upon investigation (printing the OrderedDict each time through the *second* loop) I found this (number corresponds to loop):

1. week 13 added; order: 13
2. week 14 added; order: 13, 14
3. week 15 added; order: 13, **15**, 14
4. week 16 added; order: 13, 15, 14, 16

Conclusion: during *creation and insertion of elements into the OrderedDict*, the elements are being inserted in the wrong order. I did not think that was possible.

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I resolve this?

Comment: Please post the sample data to run code on. This code is not minimal complete to reproduce the problem

Comment: Something else is wrong; ordered dictionaries very much maintain the original insertion order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting week numbers into a regular dictionary, not an ordered dictionary:

```
d_new_names[s_number] = {}
```

Here `d_new_names` in an ordered dictionary, so the `s_number` values are kept in insertion order, but the keys refer to normal dictionaries.

Then later you use those normal dictionaries to store per-week information:

```
d_new_names[s_number][s_week_number] = {}
```

Your `s_week_number` week numbers are thus not kept in insertion order, but follow the arbitrary ordering of a normal dictionary instead.

Comment: That's it! I changed the two lines you quote to: `d_new_names[s_po_number] = ordereddict.OrderedDict()` and `d_new_names[s_po_number][s_week_number] = ordereddict.OrderedDict()` and now it works, thanks so much. (6 minutes from question to solution - best I've seen with one of my questions! :) ) [And I would not have found this on my own, cheers!]

Comment: @Wikis had you included a full MCVE I could've made it 3, I'm sure. :-)